# Pentaho designer hide label depending on the page

Tags: report, pentaho, designer

I am using report designer 3.8 and have the need to have a label field and number field on every page except the front page in the page header. I have another field in the page header that must remain. I see you can show or hide the entire page header, but how do you do individual elements?

related, I have another set of elements that I want on every page except the on the last page, where I want to hide some and show others. Is there a [page] value or something to determine the current page and maximum page count?

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the "Visible" property to false to hide an element. If you want it to be dynamic, for example hide on page 1 only, you can use your pageNumber function and define the visible condition as

```
[pageNumber]>1
```

or something similar.

Every Pentaho report designer attribute can be defined using formulas which will be evaluated for each occurrence of the field.

Comment: Great I will try that. So [pageNumber] is a reference to the current page, what about the total Number of Pages? Are the docs somewhere that list all the available options? (I couldn´t get Google to show me :(

Comment: You need to create it first. Create a formula, give it the name you want (pageNumber is a good name) and choose the page number function on the list of available options.